# How to recreate cloudwatch log group for api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I enabled cloudwatch logging for one of my AWS api gateway at level INFO. (It automatically creates log group in cloudwatch under name API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_xxxxxx/stage)

But then accidentally deleted that log group ...

How could I recreate a log group for my api and ensure the api logs are delivered to that recreated log group in cloudwatch ?

Answer (score 2):

From the API GW console --> settings page, save the CW role ARN once again. It should re-create the log group.